# Is there any way to detect the state of an Outgoing call?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have to make an app which detects call state of Outgoing Call
I have to know for following events:
1.) Busy : When the operator is busy.
2.) Switch-Off : When the number is switched off of the reciever.
3.) Line-Busy : When receiver is talking with someone-else.
4.) Incorrect: When the number dialed is incorrect.
5.) Outside-coverage : When the receiver is out of coverage.

I want to know is there any way to do this in Android. Is there any package or Class in Java which have methods to detect these states?

Answer (score 0):

No, the phone state isn't that detailed.  And at least one of them is impossible-  how would the OS know you dialed the wrong number?  If you meant unassigned number, still no.

Comment: Does telecom service provide any notification or something to know any of the above states ? Moreover, can we know any one of the above states by any means.?

Comment: You can know when the phone starts a call, and when it ends. And when it rings. Using those and some logic, you can use those to figure out a missed call on your end. That's about it